# I need to configure haproxy with multiple ssl ports

Tags: rewrite, haproxy, url

I have two servers which have the same URL but the port number may change.

I want to redirect these two URLs HTTPS.

If I enter my first URL (`http://example.com`) then I want to it will redirect to `https://example.com`.

If I enter second URL (`http://example.com:8080`) then I want to it redirect to `https://example.com:8080`.

See My Configurations:

```
frontend www-HTTP
  bind *:80
  bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.pem
  reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
  default_backend tcp-backend
  mode tcp

frontend TCP-HTTP
  bind *:8080
  bind *:8443 ssl crt /etc/apache2/ssl/paritech.pem
  reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
  default_backend www-backend
  mode tcp

backend www-backend
  redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }
  server dev.example.com 192.168.1.120:8080 check

backend TCP-backend
  redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }
  server qa.example.com 192.168.1.120:80 check
```

How can I redirect 8080 over 8443 for HTTPS..

Comment: What have you tried? Also, I don't think you can use the `redirect scheme` options if you're in `mode tcp`, but I could be wrong.

Comment: if my configurations was wrong then please suggest me @GregL , I want to redirect the request to the backend for https

Comment: I think just changing your modes from `tcp` to `http` will fix it for you. In `mode tcp` the front-end will do the SSL termination, but the redirects in the backends won't work because that's a layer 7 job, which you're not doing.

Comment: in case of 80 it will work fine but not working in case of 8080 over 8443, how 8080 will know it goes to 8443 for ssl @GregL

Comment: Are you wondering how it will work, or are you saying it doesn't work?

Comment: it works for 80 redirects to https backends over 443, but 8080 not redirect. I want to take port 8443 as SSL port for 8080.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation of `redirect scheme` says

> With "redirect scheme", then the "Location" header is built by
>   concatenating  with "://" then the first occurrence of the "Host"
>   header, and then the URI path, including the query string...

There is the problem: it is using the `Host` Header and there is your `8080`...

Here is a possible solution:

```
http-request replace-header Host ^(.*?)(:[0-9]+)?$ \1:8443
http-request redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }
```

That replace the `Host` header with the correct port...